# Why does the `next` method in Ruby raises SyntaxError while `next!` or `self.next` don't while monkey patching the String class?

Tags: ruby

The following code works fine:

```
class String
  def foo
    next!
  end
end

puts 'hh'.foo    # hi
```

This one also works fine:

```
class String
  def foo
    self.next
  end
end

puts 'hh'.foo    # hi
```

But this one doesn't:

```
class String
  def bar
    next
  end
end

# Invalid next (SyntaxError)
```

Why does Ruby use the `next` keyword here and raises SyntaxError even though I am working on `String` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your first two examples, the Ruby parser is certain that you are calling methods since the `next` keyword can't be used that way.

With you third example, it looks like you are using [the `next` keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-next+Statement) instead of calling a method. The parser can't know at this stage that you actually mean to call a `next` method (which might or might not exist).

Thus, you have to guide the parser to avoid these ambiguities. You can either use an explicit receiver as in your second example or use constructs such as `send(:next)` instead

Comment: If you have a flair for the obtuse one could also use `method(:next)[]` to enforce the method call or `instance_eval(&:next)` to enforce the receiver. Usually one can even use empty parens (e.g. `next()`) to differentiate a method call from a local variable however this does not work with methods sharing a name with keywords.